# Alternative to Pyrocms Streams

Tags: php, python, stream, content-management-system, pyrocms

Those who are familiar with PyroCMS Streams.
Do you know any other similar projects that have something lika a Streams.
It can be writen in PHP, Ruby on rails, python.
It can be part of some other CMS or project.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at Symphony CMS, it's an XSLT based CMS http://www.getsymphony.com/